# БД и постройка статистика простого интернет магазина

Tags: sql, база-данных, статистика

Добрый день коллеги! Требуется ваше мнение относительно логики построения статистки Интернет магазина с использованием диаграммы Google charts. Google Charts была выбрана за свою простоту и бесплатность.

Заранее приношу извинения в SQL и бэкэнде не силен. С постройкой логики тоже большого опыта не имею.

**Что имеем:**

1. базу данных Mysql;
2. 5 таблиц куда записываются клики (1 – старый клиент, 2 – новый клиент, 3 – товар, 4 – комментарии, 5 – отзывы);

**Что необходимо:**

Задача №1. построить 5 графиков итоги кликов записанной в каждой таблицы;

Задача №2. построить на основе значений 5 таблиц - 1 график кликов по всему магазину.

**Видение автора на вопрос:**

Решение задачи №1 – так как диаграмма GC принимает готовые значения полей таблиц, сначала суммирую значение каждой строки таблицы и записываю их результат в отдельно созданную таблицу назовем её total-1 – тем самым решаем проблему с выводом диаграмм 5 таблиц.

Решение задачи №2 – далее суммирую итоги 5 таблиц и записываю во вторую созданную таблицу total-2 таким образом строиться график по всему магазину.

В результате две новые таблицы. Будет ли это оптимально и правильно построенная схема сбора данных и вывода их?

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что понял вопрос правильно, но нужно ли в вашем проекте хранить расчёт построения графика в какой-то таблице? Если такой необходимости нет, то чем же юнион не угодил?

```
SELECT <нужные поля из таблицы раз>
  FROM <таблица раз>
 WHERE <условия на таблицу раз>
 UNION ALL
SELECT <нужные поля из таблицы два>
  FROM <таблица два>
 WHERE <условия на таблицу два>
 UNION ALL
SELECT ...
```

Ограничение, конечно, в том, что набор полей в подзапросах должен быть одинаковый, но если это планировалось в одной таблице хранить, то он и так одинаковый. Аналогично и для второй задачи.
Другое дело, если таблицы огромные и неповоротливые, а доступ к этим данным нужен часто и быстро - тогда да, иногда, но имеет смысл выделить их в отдельную таблицу. Если же данные нужно один раз посчитать и один раз в день, например, обновить график, то почему бы и не просто запрос.